# Get UTC Time Information (Need People to Test my Snippet)

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

I have created a small snippet, which is supposed to return the UTC time value for the user's country based on their computer settings. However, I would be really thankful if you can test the snippet and give me some feedback if it managed to display the correct UTC value for your country. Any feedback would be high appreciated. Thank you in advance.

PS: What I learned from Wikipedia while researching how to tackle this problem is that UTC is not a time zone, therefore the 1 hour change in some countries between the winter and summer time would not affect the UTC value. However, please note that UTC is equal to GMT (Winter time) therefore for the countries which are using the summer time as of writing this post an hour has to be extracted to get the GMT (Winter Time), which in theory has to be equal to the UTC value.

```js
var currentDate = new Date();

var fetchYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
var fetchMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
var fetchDay = currentDate.getDate();
var fetchHour = currentDate.getHours();
var fetchMinutes = currentDate.getMinutes();
var fetchSeconds = currentDate.getSeconds();
var fetchMilliseconds = currentDate.getMilliseconds();

var referenceDate =  new Date(fetchYear, 0, fetchDay, fetchHour, fetchMinutes, fetchSeconds, fetchMilliseconds)

var currentDateToString = currentDate.toString().match(/[+|-].{4}/).toString();
var referenceDateToString = referenceDate.toString().match(/[+|-].{4}/).toString();

if (currentDateToString == referenceDateToString){
    document.getElementById("utcValue").innerHTML = "Output: UTC " + currentDateToString;
} else {
    document.getElementById("utcValue").innerHTML = "Output: UTC " + referenceDateToString;
}
```

```html
<div id="utcValue"></div>
```

Comment: I am in Japan and this was the output: ``UTC +0900``

Comment: @programandoconro Thank you for your feedback. It seems that it got the right UTC for your country.

Comment: Because [*Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset) is just way too simple?

Comment: @RobG, This also came into my mind but it was quickly crossed out because if we take India for example, their UTC time is +06:30 and using getTimezoneOffset would most likely return -390, which has to be divided by 60 to get the hours and as a result we would get 6.5 instead of 6:30. The same applies for New Zealand (Chatham Islands) which has UTC time of 12:45 leading to 12.75 instead of 12:45.

Comment: A solution to that would be to have the following code added 

var getMinutes = -390;
var calcHours = (getMinutes / -60);
var fixHours = Math.floor(calcHours)
var calcMinutes = (calcHours - fixHours) * 60;
var fixMinutes = Math.round(calcMinutes);
console.log(fixHours + ":" + fixMinutes);

but that way we do more calculations compared to the code above. Do you think getTimezoneOffset would give us less space for errors than my method?

Comment: What you are calling "UTC time value" is commonly called "timezone offset" or "UTC offset". The offset for India is +5:30 all year round (no daylight saving) so the ECMAScript offset is -330. Converting minutes to H:mm is simple and a lot less code than the OP, and there is `(date.toString().match(/[+-]\d\d\d\d/) || [])[0]`. In some places like Ireland, standard time (Irish Standard Time (IST) or UTC +1) is observed in summer and clocks are set back 1 hour for winter (GMT or UTC +0), so assuming the lesser offset is standard time and the other is DST is flawed.

Comment: @RobG, I think it will be good to start by saying that I am not really familiar with building RegEx statements. However, doesn't the four "\d" require to have 4 numbers after the "+" or "-"? If so, wouldn't that return "no match" if for example the offset is equal to "-60" or "-360"? Last but not least, I am not sure what "|| [])[0]" does. I would assume that you are telling to match "THIS" or "THAT", but I am not sure what "[]" is used for and for the [0] at the end I believe you are just pointing on which position to safe the match, but those are just speculations from my side.

Comment: The format of the offset in the timestamp generated by [*Date.prototype.toString*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) is ±HHmm, it's the only such pattern in the string so `/[+-]\d\d\d\d/` or `/[+-]\d{4}` matches it. `|| []` is used so just in case there is no match and *null* is returned, the expression returns an empty array and `[0]` returns *undefined* rather than throws an error. It should be extremely rare that a browser in current use doesn't generate a conforming string, but you never know…

Comment: Your `/[+-].{4}/` works as well, it's just a little less specific. You can also get *referenceDate* by `let referenceDate = new Date(currentDate); referenceDate.setMonth(0)`. The *if* block will always return the *referenceDate* offset, so why have it? For places in the southern hemisphere that observe daylight saving over the new year, it'll return the DST offset. For places in the northern hemisphere, it'll return the standard time mostly but not always (e.g. Ireland).